# How to store the row value of a logic statement in python df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

What I am trying to do is add a search feature into a dataframe. I want to be able to type a file name and save the row it was found true. That way when I use iloc it will return the "filename" and "modified_data" together.

```
import pandas as pd
#....
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['filename', 'modified_date'])
if df['filename'].str.contains('AAROW PDM Report') == TRUE:
    RowValue = #I want it to be equal to the row that was found true

print(df.iloc[[RowValue]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RowValue = df['filename'].str.contains('AAROW PDM Report').idxmax()
```

Comment: RowValue = df['filename'].str.contains('AAROW PDM Report').idxmax() Close but it gave me an error and suggested idx. But regardless it works now. Thank you.

Comment: I believed you want the line number. I fixed it.